# Accessing Environment Variables In C++

Tags: c++, environment-variables

I'd like to have access to the `$HOME` environment variable in a C++ program that I'm writing. If I were writing code in C, I'd just use the `getenv()` function, but I was wondering if there was a better way to do it. Here's the code that I have so far:

```
std::string get_env_var( std::string const & key ) {                                 
    char * val;                                                                        
    val = getenv( key.c_str() );                                                       
    std::string retval = "";                                                           
    if (val != NULL) {                                                                 
        retval = val;                                                                    
    }                                                                                  
    return retval;                                                                        
}
```

Should I use `getenv()` to access environment variables in C++? Are there any problems that I'm likely to run into that I can avoid with a little bit of knowledge?

Comment: I think you meant to return retval.

Comment: Other than the error that Ferruccio pointed out, this looks correct to me.

Comment: @grieve, tested it, it's indeed correct

Comment: maybe adding std::optional for the return type will be great too

Answer (score 95, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using `getenv()` in C++.  It is defined by `stdlib.h`, or if you prefer the standard library implementation, you can include `cstdlib` and access the function via the `std::` namespace (i.e., `std::getenv()`).  Absolutely nothing wrong with this.  In fact, if you are concerned about portability, either of these two versions is preferred.

If you are *not* concerned about portability and you are using managed C++, you can use the .NET equivalent - [`System::Environment::GetEnvironmentVariable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable.aspx).  If you want the non-.NET equivalent for Windows, you can simply use the [`GetEnvironmentVariable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683188(VS.85).aspx) Win32 function.

Comment: I dare notice that std::getenv() is actually located not in std namespace, but rather in default(null) namespace.

Comment: @shbk, there is a getenv() function defined in <stdlib.h> that is in the global namespace, which is the one you are referring to. There is also a getenv() function defined in <cstdlib> that is in the std namespace.

Comment: Actually, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/631717/1889329) suggests, that `getenv()` should not be used.

Comment: For clarity, `getenv()` accesses the snapshot of the environment variables at the time the process was created.  If the environment variables change during the lifetime of the process, `getenv()` will not see those changes.  If this is a concern, use `GetEnvironmentVariable()`.

Answer (score 51):

I would just refactor the code a little bit:

```
std::string getEnvVar( std::string const & key ) const
{
    char * val = getenv( key.c_str() );
    return val == NULL ? std::string("") : std::string(val);
}
```

Comment: Awesome solution. Simple and concise!

Comment: This isn't an "awesome solution, but you can't distinguish between a missing environment variable and an empty one.

Comment: @einpoklum I'd wager that most of the time it's not particularly useful to distinguish between the two cases. A robust program should be checking for both situations and would probably do the same thing in the "empty" case as the "not set" case. Sure there are going to be specific situations in which a very specific environment variable MUST be set and "set to empty" is meaningful, but I'd bet those are rare situations.

Comment: "I'd wager that most of the time it's not particularly useful to distinguish between the two cases"  <- "Most of the time" is nowhere near "all of the time".

Answer (score 22):

- If you are on Windows you can use the Win32 API [GetEnvironmentVariable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683188.aspx)
- On other linux/unix based systems use [getenv](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/getenv/)

Why use GetEnvironmentVariable in Windows, [from MSDN getenv](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tehxacec.aspx):

> getenv operates only on the data
>   structures accessible to the run-time
>   library and not on the environment
>   "segment" created for the process by
>   the operating system. Therefore,
>   programs that use the envp argument to
>   main or wmain may retrieve invalid
>   information.

And [from MSDN GetEnvironment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683188.aspx):

> This function can retrieve either a
>   system environment variable or a user
>   environment variable.

Comment: That's a curious comment about getenv() from MSDN.  Any idea what it really means (ie., what and when these differences might be)?

Comment: I don't know exactly but I would recommend to use GetEnvironmentVariable on windows.  It's always better to use the Win32 API.

Comment: This means that environment variables set using SetEnvironmentVariable are not accessable to genenv after the process has started.

Comment: It sounds like Microsoft didn't bother to implement the standard `getenv()` function correctly. That may not be an accurate interpretation, but it's what it wounds like.

Comment: Microsoft's [getenv](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tehxacec.aspx) is more or less a wrapper around the global [_environ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stxk41x1.aspx) variable. This variable is initialized at process start-up. If a process updates its environment through the Windows API (by calling [SetEnvironmentVariable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686206.aspx) for example), this is not reflected in the CRT `_environ` variable. The true environment is stored in the Process Environment Block (PEB), accessible through the Windows API only.

Comment: What about `C`? How can I access those on Windows in `C`?

Comment: @roy Which part of this answer do you believe doesn't apply to C?

Answer (score 10):

In c++ you have to use std::getenv and `#include <cstdlib>`

Answer (score 3):

A version of @Vlad's answer with some error checking and which distinguishes empty from missing values:

```
inline std::string_view get_env(const char* key) {
    if (key == nullptr) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Null pointer passed as environment variable name");
    }
    if (*key == '\0') {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Value requested for the empty-name environment variable");
    }
    const char* ev_val = getenv(key);
    if (ev_val == nullptr) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Environment variable not defined");
    }
    return std::string_view { ev_val };
}
```

Notes:

- You could also replace the use of exceptions in the above with an `std::optional<std::string_view>` or, in the future, with an [`std::expected`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0323r7.html).
- I've chosen safety over informativity here, by not concatenating the key into the what-string of the exception. If you make the alternative choice, try and limit copying from `key` to within reason (e.g. 100 characters? 200 characters?), and I'd also check these characters are printable, and [sanitize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34221156/c-sanitize-string-function) those characters.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I know this is an old thread! 
Still, common mistakes are, ***by definition***, not new. :-)

The only reasons I see for not just using std::getenv(),  would be to add a **known default** or to adopt common pattern/API in a **framework**. I would also avoid exceptions in this case (not generally though) simply because a non-value return is often enough a valid response for an environment variable. Adding the complexity of handling exceptions is ***counter-intuitive***.

This is basically what I use:

```
const char* GetEnv( const char* tag, const char* def=nullptr ) noexcept {
  const char* ret = std::getenv(tag);
  return ret ? ret : def; 
}
    
int main() {
  int ret=0;
  if( GetEnv("DEBUG_LOG") )  {
    // Setup debug-logging
  } else {
     ...
  }
  return (-1==ret?errno:0);
}
```

The difference between this and the other answers may seem small, but I find such small details are very rewarding when you form habits in how you code.

Just like the fact that getenv() returns a ***non-const*** pointer, which could easily lead to bad habits!