# curl_getenv() reasons of writing this function

Tags: c++, c, libcurl

I was reading libcurl and I ran into one unclear thing. 
There is one function curl_getenv(). 
It's written that it was done with idea in mind to be a wrapper for the function genenv() from stdlib.h   ( [full description of this function](http://paste.org.ru/?19cdn3))

But I can't get, what for?
 Standard functions of C  language are supported everywhere/on all platforms, where C language is supported.

So, what's the reason to write a wrapper that has the same parameters and doesn't simplify the work with it? Isn't it a useless?

Comment: See `Brian R. Bondy`'s answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631664/accessing-environment-variables-in-c
Maybe it wraps up this difference so you don't have to worry about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `curl_getenv` function is not the same as `getenv` from c lib, you can see it from the code, i think it's clear -):

```
static
char *GetEnv(const char *variable)
{
#ifdef _WIN32_WCE
  return NULL;
#else
#ifdef WIN32
  char env[MAX_PATH]; /* MAX_PATH is from windef.h */
  char *temp = getenv(variable);
  env[0] = '\0';
  if(temp != NULL)
    ExpandEnvironmentStringsA(temp, env, sizeof(env));
  return (env[0] != '\0')?strdup(env):NULL;
#else
  char *env = getenv(variable);
#ifdef __VMS
  if(env && strcmp("HOME",variable) == 0)
    env = decc_translate_vms(env);
#endif
  return (env && env[0])?strdup(env):NULL;
#endif
#endif
}

char *curl_getenv(const char *v)
{
  return GetEnv(v);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What if the names of the environment  variables, or the strings they hold, are slightly different for each platform? Then using a wrapper could enable you to hide the differences.