# C++ build full Path

Tags: c++, windows, path, environment

I can't build the full path using the variables.
How would this work?
More code as requested:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Shellapi.h>
#include <urlmon.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "urlmon.lib")
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

 wchar_t* env(wchar_t* environmentVariable)
{
    wchar_t* buffer;
    size_t bufferSize;
    errno_t errorCode;
    errorCode = _wdupenv_s(&buffer, &bufferSize, environmentVariable);
    return buffer;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE instanceHandle, HINSTANCE, char*, int)
{

    LPWSTR PSPath = env(_TEXT("SystemRoot"));
    LPWSTR TEMP2 = env(_TEXT("TEMP"));
    LPWSTR HOMEDRIVE = env(_TEXT("HOMEDRIVE"));
    LPWSTR PSPathexe = (_TEXT("powershell.exe"));
    std::stringstream BuildPath;
    BuildPath << "-noexit -Executionpolicy bypass -File (($env:temp) + '\\psscript.ps1') -Filename psscript -Folderpath (($env:systemdrive)+ '\\deployment')";
    std::string s = BuildPath.str();
    LPWSTR PSPathexe = s.c_str();


    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
    ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, PSPathexe, s, NULL, SW_SHOW);

    return 0;
}
```

The only thing I need is the Buildpath, currently build in PS in the string, I don't expect that this will work.
But I can't even convert this to LPWSTR, so I'm totally stuck here.

Comment: What's `env()` actually? Environment variables can be accessed using the [`getenv()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631664/accessing-environment-variables-in-c) function.

Comment: temp and Homedrive are neccessary here to replace the full paths of PSArg

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: did, could you help with that?