# How to distinguish if console program is opened in Powershell or in Windows Terminal?

Tags: c++, windows, powershell, winapi

I'm programming a library which will make setting colors, modes, etc. easier in console program. But I've encountered a problem with Windows Terminal. For example I have a function:

```cpp
void WindowsCLI::setUnderlinedFont()
{
    auto consoleHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    config.underlined = true;
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(consoleHandle, getTextAttribute(config));
}
```

and it uses `COMMON_LVB_UNDERSCORE` attribute from `windows.h` to make text underlined. And the result of this function in powershell looks like this:
[image], and in Windows Terminal like this:[image], so apparently in the second case my function didn't work properly. I thought that the problem is that the Windows Terminal runs in virtual terminal mode. So I made another function for virtual terminals:

```cpp
void WindowsVirtualCLI::setUnderlinedFont()
{
    printf("\x1b[4m");
}
```

and now it didn't work for Powershell: [image], and worked properly for Windows Terminal: [image]. But now I have another problem. How to distinguish that the program is run in Powershell or Windows Terminal. I tried using this function:

```cpp
CLI& cli()
{
    DWORD consoleMode;
    auto consoleHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    GetConsoleMode(consoleHandle, &consoleMode);

    if ((consoleMode & ENABLE_PROCESSED_OUTPUT) && (consoleMode & ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING))
    {
        return windows::WindowsVirtualCLI::getInstance();
    }
    else
    {
        return windows::WindowsCLI::getInstance();
    }
}
```

But it turned out that both Powershell and Windows Terminal have `ENABLE_PROCESSED_OUTPUT` and `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING` enabled. And now, I have no other idea how can I distinguish these terminals in runtime. Do you have any idea how?

P.S.
I have changed `cli()` method to this:

```cpp
CLI& cli()
{
    DWORD consoleMode;
    auto consoleHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    GetConsoleMode(consoleHandle, &consoleMode);
    SetConsoleMode(consoleHandle, consoleMode);

    if ((consoleMode & ENABLE_PROCESSED_OUTPUT) && (consoleMode & ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING))
    {
        return windows::WindowsVirtualCLI::getInstance();
    }
    else
    {
        return windows::WindowsCLI::getInstance();
    }
}
```

And still it doesn't work as I need to.

Comment: You're calling `GetConsoleMode` but not `SetConsoleMode`, the shell shouldn't matter if you set it to `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING`. That's a function of the console host not the shell.

Comment: Should you be using `GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)` (I don't know much about Windows console, it might not make any difference)

Comment: @AlanBirtles they at a minimum need to set the output mode to VT support on that handle. Otherwise the console host has no idea what to do! That said if the console is using VT.... then they need to use VT sequences and not legacy

Comment: @Mgetz I haven't called SetConsoleMode, because I don't want to set any mode. I just wanted to see if these flags are true

Comment: Then call `GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)`. You are currently calling it for `STD_INPUT_HANDLE` which doesn't make sense.

Comment: @AndrzejSołtysik then you're trying to output in an indeterminate mode. You need to set that so the console host knows what you're intending.

Comment: @zett42 I have changed the function to use output handle and I set the mode, to the mode which already was, but nothing changed :/

Comment: Indeed it's strange that Windows PowerShell reports `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING` while actually not processing VT100 sequences. I have confirmed that with PowerShell code too.

Comment: @zett42 except they are using classic terminal sequences not VT100 which would be in the string. This looks like expected behavior.

Comment: Powershell is not a terminal/console at all. Perhaps you mean the older conhost terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simple, but not foolproof solution**:

Windows Terminal defines two application-specific environment variables, `WT_SESSION` and `WT_PROFILE_ID`, so you can test whether one of these variables is defined (with a non-empty value).

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/631728/45375), **`getenv("WT_SESSION")`** should work in C++ for retrieving the value of that variable, if defined.

In PowerShell itself, `[bool] $env:WT_SESSION` returns `$true` if the  variable has a non-empty value.

This approach isn't foolproof, because if you launch a regular console window (`conhost.exe`) *from a shell running in Windows Terminal* - e.g. with `Start-Process cmd.exe` - it'll *inherit* the `WT_SESSION` variable and thus produce a false positive in such sessions.

---

**More elaborate, but robust solution**:

A robust solution is to walk the chain of parent processes starting with the current process until the first process with an associated main window handle is found:

- If that process' name is `WindowsTerminal`, it is safe to assume that the process is running in Windows Terminal - possibly indirectly, in a (by definition console-subsystem) process launched from the shell running directly in Windows Terminal.
- Otherwise, it is safe to assume that a *different* application is hosting the process, possibly the process itself (a process running in a regular console window itself owns that window, and has a `conhost.exe` *child* process).

The following are *PowerShell* implementations:

- **PowerShell (Core) 7+** implementation:

```bash
$runningInWindowsTerminal = 
  if ($IsWindows) {
    $ps = Get-Process -Id $PID
    while ($ps -and 0 -eq [int] $ps.MainWindowHandle) { $ps = $ps.Parent }
    $ps.ProcessName -eq 'WindowsTerminal'
  } else {
    $false
  }
```

- **Windows PowerShell** and cross-edition implementation:

Unfortunately, Windows PowerShell doesn't decorate the  [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process) objects output by `Get-Process` with a `.Parent` property reporting the parent process, which complicates the solution and requires a `Get-CimInstance` call to retrieve the parent information.

```bash
$runningInWindowsTerminal = 
  if ($env:OS -eq 'Windows_NT') {
    $ps = Get-Process -Id $PID
    while ($ps -and 0 -eq [int] $ps.MainWindowHandle) { 
      $ps = Get-Process -ErrorAction Ignore -Id (Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessID = $($ps.Id)").ParentProcessId 
    }
    $ps.ProcessName -eq 'WindowsTerminal'
  } else {
    $false
  }
```